# Android ListActivity - Switching between empty and non-empty list

Tags: android, android-listview

Given my xml file below, I want to show the `ListView` when my object list is not empty and I want to show the `ViewStub` when my list is empty. I can get this to work, but whenever I change screen orientations, I lose the new data that I've added to my list.

Basically, any time I add a new object, I call my adapter's changeData() method which changes the object list and calls the method `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Any advice on how to make sure this change persists across all views?

(There's more in the XML but it's irrelevant):

```
    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>

    <ViewStub android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout="@layout/empty" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to maintain your screen state by using the savedInstanceState `Bundle` which is available in the `onCreate()` method.
Every time when you change your screen orientation `onCreate()` is called.

here an example : [[CLICK]](http://onegullibull.com/WP-OneGulliBull/?p=252)

Comment: I got it to work by adding this to my AndroidManifest

<activity android:name="YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>

Comment: Adding the configChanges thing to your manifest is a quick and dirty work around and doesn't really solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you saving the data? The problem would seem to be that you are not persisting it anywhere when your Activity is destroyed. Your Activity can be destroyed on an orientation change, but this can also happen when you are in the background and the system runs low on memory.

I suggest you save the data somewhere in an onPause, onStop or onDestroy call, and reload it in the corresponding onResume, onStart or onCreate.